# Moving Algorithm in GridWorld

Tags: java, string, gridworld

In the grid world case study foe my final project I am making a game. In the game if the player clicks the "W" key the shiftUp() method is called which makes all of the other actors of a certain instance move down to create the illusion of the player moving. This isn't a finished implementation of the method but this should get all the actors in the grid and test if they are an instance of a class called Enemy which extends Actor. If so the actor should move up one space. When I call this method a NullPointerException is called on the line that calls enemy.moveTo(...); This shouldn't happen because I check to see if it's null. Can anyone help me with this? I get this:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public void shiftUp()
{
    if (((GameGrid)getGrid()).getMinX() != 0)
    {
        Grid<Actor> grid = getGrid();
        if (grid != null)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < getGrid().getNumRows(); y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < getGrid().getNumCols(); x++)
                {
                    Actor enemy = grid.get(new Location(y,x));
                    if (enemy != null && enemy instanceof Enemy)
                        enemy.moveTo(new Location(enemy.getLocation().getRow() - 1, enemy.getLocation().getCol()));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the exception? Is it possible that `getLocation()` is returning `null`?

Comment: This is what it says: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Comment: @Mobianhero, Add the full stacktrace to your question by editing it.

Comment: your right for some reason it is getLocation() that is turning up null

Comment: @Mobianhero What comes after that line? That is the first line of the stack trace, the remaining portion of it tells us which line number(s) caused the exception.

Comment: it says the : enemy.moveTo(new Location(enemy.getLocation().getRow() - 1, enemy.getLocation().getCol())); caused the problem

Comment: I replaced all of the params with actual positions in the grid but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are checking for `enemy != null` beforehand, I'm guessing that `enemy.getLocation()` is returning `null`, which is causing a `NullPointerException` when you call `null.getRow()` and `null.getCol()`.

If this is the case, then it looks like the problem is that your `Actor` is never given a proper `Location` in the grid. Make sure you are using the `putSelfInGrid(Grid<Actor> grid, Location loc)` method to place the `Actor` in the grid (*not* `grid.put(Location loc, E obj)`), as `putSelfInGrid()` sets your `Actor`'s location accordingly.

Comment: Still got it even after 3 years of not doing `GridWorld`, ya! :P